# How to convert listiterator object to tree object?

Tags: python

I want to extract parse trees by running find_pattern.py , those are matches with following patterns :

```
SIMPLE_PREDICATE = (ROOT, ((SENTENCE, (NP, VP, PERIOD)),))          
APPOSITION = (SENTENCE, ((NP, (NP, COMMA, NP, COMMA)), VP, PERIOD))
```

But following output shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\ZAHID\Working Model 1\zahid\Practice\New folder\find_pattern.py", line 40, in <module>
appos = sent_extract.find_appositions(parse_trees)
 File "C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\ZAHID\Working Model 1\zahid\Practice\New folder\sent_extract.py", line 30, in find_appositions
s in search_for_matches(parse_tree, APPOSITION)]
 File "C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\ZAHID\Working Model 1\zahid\Practice\New folder\sent_extract.py", line 58, in search_for_matches
if is_match(parse_tree, pattern):
 File "C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\ZAHID\Working Model 1\zahid\Practice\New folder\sent_extract.py", line 45, in is_match
if tree.label() == parent and len(tree) == len(children): 
AttributeError: 'listiterator' object has no attribute 'label'
```

find_pattern.py

```
import os
import parse_article
import stanford_parser
import sent_extract

article_filename = 'C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\ZAHID\Working Model 1\zahid\Practice\New folder\____.html'

sentences = parse_article.parse_html(article_filename)

user='' 
parser = stanford_parser.create_parser(user)
parse_trees = parser.raw_parse_sents(sentences)

appos = sent_extract.find_appositions(parse_trees)
print(appos)
```

sent_extract.py

```
from nltk.tree import Tree
from tags import *

SIMPLE_PREDICATE = (ROOT, ((SENTENCE, (NP, VP, PERIOD)),))          
APPOSITION = (SENTENCE, ((NP, (NP, COMMA, NP, COMMA)), VP, PERIOD)) 

def find_predicates(parse_trees):
  preds = []
  for parse_tree in parse_trees:
    if is_match(parse_tree, SIMPLE_PREDICATE):         
      preds.append(parse_tree[0])
  return preds

def find_appositions(parse_trees):
  appos = []
  for parse_tree in parse_trees:
    appos += [(s[0,0], s[0,2]) for
        s in search_for_matches(parse_tree, APPOSITION)]
  return appos


def is_match(tree, pattern):
  if not isinstance(pattern, tuple):
    return tree.label() == pattern

  else:
    parent = pattern[0]
    children = pattern[1]
    if tree.label() == parent and len(tree) == len(children): 
      for i in xrange(len(tree)):
        ith_child = tree[i]
        if not is_match(ith_child, children[i]):
          return False
      return True

def search_for_matches(parse_tree, pattern):
  matches = []
  if is_match(parse_tree, pattern):
    matches.append(parse_tree)
  for child in parse_tree:
    if isinstance(child, Tree):
      matches += search_for_matches(child, pattern)
  return matches
```

tags.py

```
ADJP = 'ADJP'
ADVP = 'ADVP'
NUMBER = 'CD'
DET = 'DT'
PREP = 'IN'
ADJ = 'JJ'
ADJ_COMP = 'JJR'
ADJ_SUP = 'JJS'
MODAL = 'MD'
NOUN = 'NN'
NOUN_PROPER = 'NNP'
NOUN_PL = 'NNS'
NP = 'NP'
POSS = 'POS'
PP = 'PP'
PRONOUN = 'PRP'
PRONOUN_POSS = 'PRP$'
ADVERB = 'RB'
ROOT = 'ROOT'
SENTENCE = 'S'
SBAR = 'SBAR'
WH_QUESTION = 'SBARQ'
BIN_QUESTION = 'SQ'
TO = 'TO'
VERB_INF = 'VB'
VERB_PAST = 'VBD'
VERB_PLURAL = 'VBP'
VERB_3SG = 'VBZ'
VP = 'VP'
WHNP = 'WHNP'
WHADJP = 'WHADJP'
WHADVP = 'WHADVP'
WDT = 'WDT'
WP_POSS = 'WP$'
COMMA = ','
PERIOD = '.'
```

Comment: `parser.raw_parse_sents()` returns an iterator over a list, and each entry itself is another iterator, over a list of `Tree` objects. I'm not sure what object you expected instead, but there is no `.label()` attribute on a iterator objects.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to call `.label()` on some *content* of the iterable? You don't have a single tree, you have a sequence of trees.

Comment: I wanted to call label() method , on the a sequence of trees; those I got from parsing. How can I do this? In following I gave the article I work on and trees that I got:

Comment: What would that do? What output would you expect, given an iterable of multiple `Tree` objects?

Comment: After parsing I got a sequence of tree pattterns. I want found those patterns from these those are APPOSITION using the following function, but it shows the error:                                                                                                                            def find_appositions(parse_trees):
  appos = []
  for parse_tree in parse_trees:
    appos += [(s[0,0], s[0,2]) for
        s in search_for_matches(parse_tree, APPOSITION)]
  return appos

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But then you'd just access the `Tree()` instances in the sub-iterators. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`raw_parse_sents()` method](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html#nltk.parse.stanford.GenericStanfordParser.raw_parse_sents) is designed to handle *multiple sentences*. Each sentence is parsed into a sequence of trees, but your code is assuming that you have a single tree per sentence. From the documentation:

> Return type:  `iter(iter(Tree))`

so you are given an iterable of iterables of trees.

So rather than use

```
for parse_tree in parse_trees:
    if is_match(parse_tree, SIMPLE_PREDICATE):         
        preds.append(parse_tree[0])
```

You'd have to use

```
for sentence in parse_trees:
    for parse_tree in sentence:
        if is_match(parse_tree, SIMPLE_PREDICATE):         
            preds.append(parse_tree[0])
```

Now you are passing in actual [`Tree()` instances](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree), which are list-like objects that can be indexed and have a length.

The same applies to `find_appositions()`:

```
def find_appositions(parse_trees):
    appos = []
    for sentence in parse_trees:
        for parse_tree in sentence:
            appos += [(s[0,0], s[0,2]) for
                      s in search_for_matches(parse_tree, APPOSITION)]
    return appos
```

Comment: I am facing problem with def find_appositions(parse_trees): function. Please , give me the full function that does not show the error.

Comment: @Zahid: without an error, that's very hard to answer.

Comment: what about the return statement for for sentence in parse_trees: .It shows File "C:\Users\MD. ZAHIDUR RAHMAN\Desktop\QA - ask program\sent_extract.py", line 28
    return preds
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: @Zahid: are you perhaps mixing tabs and spaces? The code posted here does not have such a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks,@Martijn  I corrected my code as you told, for find_apposition function and it gives result for the first sentence only and it also shows error to implement next line of find_pattern.py    --- appo_sentences = [sent_transform.apposition_to_sent(appo) for appo in appos] . Please see my question again, it is updated.

Comment: @Zahid: sorry, questions here should sick to a single problem; once answered, new problems should be posted in new questions. I've rolled back the edit. Remember that Stack Overflow aims to be a resource for future visitors, and multiple problems make it much harder to identify if someone has the same problem to solve!

Comment: @Zahid: your new error is self-explanatory though. You called the `apposition_to_sent()` function with just one argument, the function takes two arguments. Pass in two arguments or update the function to only require one argument.